# What does *allow-unresolved-vars* do in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Like there is no official document for it
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/*allow-unresolved-vars*

Comment: Seems only used internally, a flag that omitting unresolved symbol, make compiling a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

*Apologies -- this is not a complete answer.  I haven't figured out everything about it yet.*

---

`*allow-unresolved-vars*` is defined in [RT.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/43cc1854508d655e58e377f84836ba128971f90c/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L227):

```
final static Var ALLOW_UNRESOLVED_VARS = Var.intern(CLOJURE_NS, Symbol.intern("*allow-unresolved-vars*"), F).setDynamic();
```

and used in [Compiler.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/43cc1854508d655e58e377f84836ba128971f90c/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6934):

```
    if(o == null)
        {
        if(RT.booleanCast(RT.ALLOW_UNRESOLVED_VARS.deref()))
            {
            return sym;
            }
        else
            {
            throw Util.runtimeException("Unable to resolve symbol: " + sym + " in this context");
            }
        }
```

So clearly, its use here is to decide whether or not an exception should be **immediately** thrown when an unresolved symbol is encountered.

You can mess with it like so:

```
myns.core=> (ns clojure.core)
nil

clojure.core=> oops!
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: oops! in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1596111142512149454.clj:1:884) 

clojure.core=> (defn q [] (oops!))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: oops! in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1596111142512149454.clj:1:12) 

clojure.core=> (def *allow-unresolved-vars* true)
Warning: *allow-unresolved-vars* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *allow-unresolved-vars* or change the name. (/tmp/form-init1596111142512149454.clj:1)
#'clojure.core/*allow-unresolved-vars*

clojure.core=> oops!
IllegalArgumentException UnresolvedVarExpr cannot be evalled  clojure.lang.Compiler$UnresolvedVarExpr.eval (Compiler.java:1771)
clojure.core=> 

clojure.core=> (defn q [] (oops!))
CompilerException java.lang.VerifyError: (class: clojure/core$q, method: invoke signature: ()Ljava/lang/Object;) Unable to pop operand off an empty stack, compiling:(form-init1596111142512149454.clj:1:1)
```

But I haven't figured out a use yet, because unresolved variables still cause errors -- they're just different errors.  Also, I don't understand the warning when re-`def`-ing it, because the warning says that it's not declared dynamic, whereas it looks to me as though it is declared dynamic in RT.java.

Comment: You get the warning because you're redefining it, rather than setting the existing one. You'd use `alter-var-root` or perhaps `set!`, depending on context, to modify the existing var.